# Aerospike python client: return only bins data (no key details and no metadata)

Tags: aerospike

I have a record that I've set using:

```
client.put(key, {bin: value})
```

I want to select the record but get only:

```
{bin: value}
```

Instead of the default retuned value of client.get(key) which is

```
(key, metadata(ttl stuff), {bin: value})
```

Is it possible without any overhead? which is what I'm trying to save here.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to skip the metadata in the response. But the metadata overhead is very small. So, it should not hurt. If you are copying the result to something else for further processing, you can copy only the bin portion.